# How do i make MongoDB work (MERN APP) using IIS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, iis

I hosted my build folder on IIS and i want to connect to my Database locally as a service and i get:

```
 You have failed to connect to a MongoDB Atlas cluster. Please ensure that your IP whitelist allows connections from your network.
```

I also did this:

and go to your `MongoDB Atlas -> NetworkAccess-> Edit-`> and add Current IP address.

I added it still getting the same Error. Maybe i'm doing something wrong.

The question is when i reference my build folder from IIS, how do i make mongoDB work locally?

Answer (score 0):

First please check if your IP address is correct, then you can refer to this link about [how to whitelist IP addresses on MongoDB Atlas](https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/mongodb-atlas-login-ip-whitelisting/#how-to-whitelist-ip-addresses-on-mongodb-atlas).

Note: You need to use your MongoDB Atlas login credentials, open your account and find the cluster that is triggering the error message.

If it still doesn’t work, you can try [add your connection IP address to IP access list](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security/add-ip-address-to-list/).